# How do I count up if a student has selected Biology, Chemistry, and/or Physics

Tags: google-sheets

I've tried Pivot tables, countif (Parse error) and the Query function, although I'm not very good with it yet. What is your suggestion?

[image]

The answer would return either a 1, 2 or 3 in column P

Comment: Actually, I can create 3 different pivot tables for the 3 different subjects and then do another pivot or simple sum of the grand totals , but I'm looking for something more simple please :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=AND(E2=="Biology";F2=="DT";G2=="Business Studies")
```

*Edit:*
I am using European Excel, maybe there are some differencess in syntax. But maybe the idea could help you.

Answer (score 1):

**`COUNTIF` with 'OR operator':**

```
=COUNTIF(E2:G2,"Biology")+COUNTIF(E2:G2,"Chemistry")+COUNTIF(E2:G2,"Physics")
```

**`QUERY`:**

```
=IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(E2:G2),"select count(Col1) where Col1 matches 'Biology|Chemistry|Physics' label count(Col1) ''"),0)
```

Comment: You are amazing! And so simple. I thought there was a way. Thank you so much.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)